# Idea 13 Ultimate, groovy plugin, seems doesn't work with $HOME/.groovy directory with classes

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I'm working with Idea 13 Ultimate and groovy plugin, but when I'm trying to use @Grab to add third party libraries I can't run my script in Idea, it fails with "ClassNotFound" exception. At the same time it works OK when I run it from command line.

So it seems to me that Idea doesn't work with $HOME/.groovy directory for some reason. Could you please advise how can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Alt+Enter + "Grab dependencies" while your caret is on the Grab annotation?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no such option..

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot of your editor with Alt+Enter menu open at that position?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question, please take a look..

Comment: Please place the caret on the Grab annotation itself and try Alt+Enter.

Comment: Uh, thanks a lot! Didn't try that.

Comment: Does that help? I've filed a request to support your use case, too: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122995

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but pressing alt-enter with caret on @Grab does not show a "Grab dependencies" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this from comments. To make IDEA see the jars used by Groovy Grape, put your caret on the @Grab annotation in your code, press Alt+Enter and choose "Grab dependencies".